# Logging in Android App Using the data from database of ASP.net C#

Tags: c#, android, asp.net

I already used SOAP for getting the Idnumber from the database of ASp.net C# and I created  an App that he/she can log using Email and Password and will go to next activity. This is the code that is used for trying to logged in using the Email and Password in WebSite.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        EditText Email, Password;
        Button button;
        TextView error;
        String EmailAddfromWeb, PassfromWeb;

    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/findContact";    
        private static final String OPERATION_NAME = "CheckLogin";    
        private static final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";    
        private static final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://10.0.2.2:64485/WebService.asmx";

   @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        Password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        error = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v){

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,    OPERATION_NAME);
                PropertyInfo propertyInfo = new PropertyInfo();
                propertyInfo.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                propertyInfo.name = "EmailAdd";


                EmailAddfromWeb = Email.getText().toString();

                request.addProperty(propertyInfo, EmailAddfromWeb);

                        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                        SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                        envelope.dotNet = true;

                        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

                        HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);

                        try
                        {
                            httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);                    
                            Object response = envelope.getResponse();  
                            error.setText(response.toString());



                SPLPVIEWER s = new SPLPVIEWER();
          Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SPLPVIEWER.class);
                            Bundle b = new Bundle();

                            b.putString(s.holder, "" + String.valueOf(Email));
                            intent.putExtras(b);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        }
                        catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            error.setText("Invalid Email!");
                        }





            }

        });
```

Code for WebService.asmx.cs :
How can i compare my data login in Web Service from the inputted in AndroidApplication.

```
      using System;
      using System.Linq;
      using System.Web;
      using System.Web.Services;
      using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
      using System.Xml.Linq;
      using System.Data.SqlClient;
      using System.Data;

      [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
      [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]

      public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
      {
        public WebService()
        {


        }

        [WebMethod]
        public bool CheckLogin(string EmailAdd, string Password)
        {

          return getEmail(EmailAdd, Password);
        }


        public bool getEmail(String EmailAdd, String Password)
        {

          SqlConnection conn;
          conn = ConnectionManager.GetConnection();
          conn.Open();
          bool check = false;
          string pa;



         SqlCommand CheckCmd = new SqlCommand("CheckEmailAddress", conn);
         CheckCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
         CheckCmd.Parameters.Add("@EmailAddress", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = EmailAdd;

         SqlDataReader sdr = CheckCmd.ExecuteReader();



         while (sdr.Read())
         {
             pa = sdr.GetString(8); // for Password column

             if (pa == Password)
             {
               check = true;
             }
              break;
         }

    conn.Close();
    return check;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use asp Web service or simple post methods.
[image]

Try this http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/
Build your xml page via asp.net.

Comment: thanks sir for your reply. i  don't know how to use JSON can you please give me some tutorials :)

Comment: Hmm,you dont want to use json,you can use even xml,basic is here.. asp page wating for post request,the you can send httprequest using android with your parameters,ex username,password,asp page check that passwords ok then send the "ok" message to as web response,while asp page send the response you can convert responce code as xml like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><login>OK</logn>`.after android application read the response and filter xml tags and get the result.

Comment: even you don't need to use web service.make simple asp page with get parameter,call that page using android `httprequst` get the result display it,same scenario to use your project

Comment: check my blog post to write android `httprequest` http://devoptions.blogspot.com/2013/09/android-web-request-sample.html

Comment: Sir, I updated my post. Thanks for taking so much time to this thread.